# ApplicationClass ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, classnotfoundexception

I'm using the application class , so I had to create the manifest file, as follows:

```
<application
    android.name="com.moonae.android.common.ApplicationClass"
    android.icon="@drawble/ic_launcher"
    android.largeHeap="true"
    ....>
<activity..../>
```

---

I have to work normally without problems when testing , often the error occurred in the Google Play Store error report.
But the error report is posted on the Android version 4.4 , I even tested at 4.4 operate normally.
If the person experiencing this problem help me.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.moonae.android.common.ApplicationClass: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.culturelandnew.android.common.ApplicationClass" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:516)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4524)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:163)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.moonae.android.common.ApplicationClass" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:993)
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:511)
... 11 more
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<application
   android.name="com.moonae.android.common.ApplicationClass"
   android.icon="@drawble/ic_launcher"
   android.largeHeap="true"
   ....>
<activity..../>
```

is this a typo? i have not seen this before i mean `android.name` to `android:name`..btw

quick suggestion, remove your application tag, and use the eclipse gui side to search the application class and reference it.. mostly it references the it without package name included.. like this.. =>

```
<application
 android:name="ApplicationClass"
 android:icon="@drawble/ic_launcher"
 android:largeHeap="true"
 ....>
```